# Xna 4.0 WP, SpriteBatch - Animation

Tags: xna, windows-phone

I have this code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{          
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Vector2 m = new Vector2(0, 0);  
    Texture2D polska;        
    int i = 1;

    //Game class boilerplate code snipped for brevity.

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        polska = Content.Load<Texture2D>(i.ToString());
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(polska, m, null, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        if (i == 169)
            i = 1;
        else
            i++;

        base.Draw(gameTime);              
    }          
}
```

The problem is when I run this on my phone, it only shows 1 image, and it should be showing 169 different images (they are named `[number].png`).

What is wrong?

Comment: i did mistake it only show 90 frames.

Comment: Try setting `i=91` at the start of your program to see what happens.

Comment: i did 91 - stop at 90 and if i do 89 it looping/

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean with your results.  Did you declare `int i=91;`?  And if so, what do you mean stop at 90?  And what do you mean by "do 89"?

Comment: i can tell it is looping why i did in if (i==89) , but if (i==90) not looping , just error at 90 frame

Comment: i did at start i=91 and it show next 90 frames. After this 90 frames it exit

Comment: ok. That's good to know.  Since it seems to load 90 frames, and then no more, you may be looking at a limitation of the environment - only 90 textures loaded.  Or maybe you are running out of memory.  You could try smaller images (stretch them to make them larger), or try `Content.Unload()` before each load call.

Comment: Content.Unload()  - this is what help.

Comment: But tell my why i need to free memory if i reload only 1 var ?

Comment: Because `Content.Load` caches the things it loads.  Even though you don't explicitly save a reference to the texture between frames, the Content Manager does save it.  Even though `Content.Unload()` fixes the problem, I would still consider trying something else.  Smaller images may work.  Also, you could load images with multiple images embedded, and then only show part of the image per frame.

Comment: it is a way but my images are high resolution soo if i try to make this image on gimp ( resolution 1024 x about 360 000 ) it tell me that image size is about 2,6GB so gimp cant create this image . Is a way to reduce a size of my animation ?

Comment: You are probably maxing out your memory - see this article for Phone memory information: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Try using smaller images.  Downsize them using gimp.

Comment: thats good idea but i have 1 more problem if i try display this animation it's lagging , is a better way to do it ?

Comment: Yes.  Load all images during `LoadContent` and don't call `Content.Unload` until you are done with them entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be loading content in your `Draw` method since that updates >30 times per second, and loading a texture takes time. Instead, load all the images *ONCE* in the `LoadContent` method (using an array or list to store them) and then draw the correct image in the `Draw` method:

```
Texture2D[] polska = new Texture2D[169];//array of textures

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    for (int j = 0; j < 169; j++)
        polska[j] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(j.ToString());//load all the images here


    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}


protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(polska[i],m,null,Color.White);//draw the current (i) image
    spriteBatch.End();
    if (i == 169)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
    base.Draw(gameTime);

}
```

HTH, lmk if anything's unclear.

NOTE: As @StevenHansen pointed out, you should resize your textures so that you don't get an out of memory excpetion.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.  Just make sure you don't overflow your memory.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll say something about the size of the textures (I saw your comments) :)

Comment: david , can you tell me if i declares an array - this array is on memory - soo it take ( about 169*2 mb ) is a way to take only 2mb memory ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. :) Are you asking to find how big the array is? Or how to shrink it? Or what?

Comment: i asked , how to shrink a used momory and not lost any resolution of image.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could ask another question on that. But techincally, the textures you use only have to be as big as the screen, so I would see if I could do that first.

Comment: soo just tell me how games are fullscreen and they too have big resolution for example Ashpalt 8

Comment: Draw can be updated so fact because programmers try to minimize the code running in draw. If you removed the `Content.Load()` from your draw method, you should've noticed an improvement. Also, XNA has a fullscreen mode `Graphics.IsFullScreen`